Why Does NVIDIA Megatron Load Dataset Iterators Multiple Times Based on Model Size?
I'm working with NVIDIA's Megatron code, specifically regarding the dataset loading section. I noticed that the build_train_valid_test_data_iterators function is executed multiple times—specifically, it runs len(model) times, where len(model) corresponds to the value of virtual_pipeline_model_parallel_size. This significantly slows down the execution.
Why is the code designed this way? If I move the build_train_valid_test_data_iterators call outside of the loop, what negative impacts might that have?
Here's the relevant code snippet for context:
# Model, optimizer, and learning rate.
timers('model-and-optimizer-setup', log_level=0).start(barrier=True)
model, optimizer, opt_param_scheduler = setup_model_and_optimizer(
    model_provider, model_type)

timers('model-and-optimizer-setup').stop()
print_datetime('after model, optimizer, and learning rate '
               'scheduler are built')
config = get_model_config(model[0])

# Data stuff.
timers('train/valid/test-data-iterators-setup', log_level=0).start(
    barrier=True)
if args.virtual_pipeline_model_parallel_size is not None:
    train_data_iterator = []
    valid_data_iterator = []
    test_data_iterator = []
    for i in range(len(model)):
        mpu.set_virtual_pipeline_model_parallel_rank(i)
        iterators = build_train_valid_test_data_iterators(
            train_valid_test_dataset_provider)
        train_data_iterator.append(iterators[0])
        valid_data_iterator.append(iterators[1])
        test_data_iterator.append(iterators[2])
else:
    train_data_iterator, valid_data_iterator, test_data_iterator \
        = build_train_valid_test_data_iterators(
            train_valid_test_dataset_provider)

I tried moving the build_train_valid_test_data_iterators function call outside of the loop that executes len(model) times. I expected this change to improve the performance by reducing redundant data loading operations, resulting in faster training initialization.
